# Pandas only select rows where unique string in column only has one specific string in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEST_NAME':['A','A','B','B','C','D','E','E','F'],
                   'ID':['4624','4625','4624','4625','4625','4625','4624','4625','4625'],
                   'COUNT':[203,202,100,23,2,200,203,2022,201]})

    DEST_NAME   ID      COUNT
0   A           4624    203
1   A           4625    202
2   B           4624    100
3   B           4625    23
4   C           4625    2
5   D           4625    200
6   E           4624    203
7   E           4625    2022
8   F           4625    201
9   D           4625    125
10  D           4625    122
11  C           4625    3
```

I am try to get rows where a `DEST_NAME` only has an `ID` of `4625` and not `4624`.  So essentially exclude if the `DEST_NAME` has both `4624` and `4625` entries in column `ID`. So the result would look like:

```
    DEST_NAME   ID      COUNT
0   C           4625    2
1   D           4625    200
2   F           4625    201
3   D           4625    125
4   D           4625    122
5   C           4625    3
```

Comment: Are you trying to get DEST_NAME that has only ID 4625? Like 'A' DEST_NAME would be excluded?

Comment: That is correct @LucasHort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract in-scope and out-of-scope `DEST_NAME`s. Then use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and combine your two conditions:

```
ids_inc = df.loc[df['ID'] == '4625', 'DEST_NAME']
ids_exc = df.loc[df['ID'] == '4624', 'DEST_NAME']

res = df[df['DEST_NAME'].isin(ids_inc) & ~df['DEST_NAME'].isin(ids_exc)]

print(res)

   COUNT DEST_NAME    ID
4      2         C  4625
5    200         D  4625
8    201         F  4625
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check which rows contain an `ID` of `4625` and `GroupBy` `DEST_NAME` to keep only those where all values are `True`. Then use these values to perform boolean indexation on the dataframe:

```
m = df.ID.eq('4625').groupby(df.DEST_NAME).all()
df[df.DEST_NAME.isin(m[m].index)]

    COUNT DEST_NAME    ID
4      2         C  4625
5    200         D  4625
8    201         F  4625
```

Comment: For this, probably better to just filter your dataframe for `'4625'` using `loc`, extract `'DEST_NAME'`, then use `loc` again. Of course, `groupby` does work, just less efficient since dataframe Boolean indexing is more efficient than `groupby`.

Comment: Yes True @jpp it is a more efficient solution, focused it in a different way. Thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_filtered = df[df['ID'] == '4625'].copy()
```

Comment: That brings back all DEST_NAME's that have '4625' in the 'ID' column.  I am looking to exclude any "DEST_NAME' that has '4624' as well. @Lucas Hort

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEST_NAME':['A','A','B','B','C','D','E','E','F'],
                   'ID':['4624','4625','4624','4625','4625','4625','4624','4625','4625'],
                   'COUNT':[203,202,100,23,2,200,203,2022,201]})

df2=df[df['ID']=='4625']
```

result :

```
COUNT DEST_NAME    ID
1    202         A  4625
3     23         B  4625
4      2         C  4625
5    200         D  4625
7   2022         E  4625
8    201         F  4625
```

Comment: That brings back all DEST_NAME's that have '4625' in the 'ID' column. I am looking to exclude any "DEST_NAME' that has '4624' as well. @Antoine Soulier

Answer (score 0):

I find the [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method to be an elegant way to filter data. I guess in your case it would give:

```
df.query("ID == '4625' & ID != 4624")
```